# How to create a function that can operate with the current date and a value from my table in sql

Tags: sql

I have a `Clients` table with the `inscriptiondate` which is a `date`. I want to create a function that I give the value `inscriptiondate`(from my table) and do the `value-currdate()`. Is it possible?

I'm using SQL server, But I would also like to know how to do in Mysql if its different.

Comment: You need to specify which DBMS you are using (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle etc.) as the answer won't necessarily be the same.

Comment: I updated it , thanks

Comment: For Sql Server or MySql use the datediff function.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you would typically do:

```
select datediff(curdate(), inscriptiondate) as days_between
```

In MS SQL, you would typically do:

```
select datediff(day, inscriptiondate, getdate())
```